# Create Xaml elemenents in Async Method

Tags: xaml, asynchronous, windows-store-apps

i have a method grabs data from sqlite database and according to the data some xaml element are created this method are kind of heavy method. i'm trying to execute it asynchronously but it gives me that exception:

```
The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread 

   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel..ctor()
   at Helper.DrawPage.InitPage()
   at Helper.PageProvider.GetPage(Int32 chapterIndex, Int32 pageIndex)
   at WinRT.View.Main.loadPages()
   at WinRT.View.Main.<TurnPageNext_Completed>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

my code:

```
        public void loadPages()
        {

            PageProvider pageProvider = new PageProvider();
            pageProvider.SetPageSize(new Size(400, 564));
            FrameworkElement fm =  pageProvider.GetPage(0, (currentPage + 2));
            fm.Name = "c_" + ((currentPage + 2) + 1);
            Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => pageContent.Add(fm));
}
```

thanks

```
//animation completed event
async void TurnPageNext_Completed(object sender, object e)
        {
 await Task.Run(() => loadPages());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FrameworkElements` need to be created on a dispatcher thread too, so perhaps your `pageProvider.GetPage()` call runs on a background thread and throws. You can try enabling breaking on first chance exceptions (Ctrl+Alt+E, check all applicable) to see where the exception originally occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Task.Run starts a new thread to create the page in then you add the FrameworkElement back to the UI thread with Dispatcher.RunAsync.  That's why you're getting the error, FrameworkElement  fm is from a different thread.

Create FrameworkElement fm in the UI thread async like this:

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,()=>{
    PageProvider pageProvider = new PageProvider();
    pageProvider.SetPageSize(new Size(400, 564));
    FrameworkElement fm =  pageProvider.GetPage(0, (currentPage + 2));
    fm.Name = "c_" + ((currentPage + 2) + 1);
    pageContent.Add(fm)
});
```